# Collection is not being saved to Cloud Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Wrtitten in React-redux.

I have given it my all to resolve this problem on my own. Here is my firebase.utils file. I have tried using a private window, disabling all my extensions and I reverted my hosts file back to the original version. The thing is, this problem is only happening to me. I am following along with a Udemy course and have asked members of the community if the code is working for them (it is). I even cloned the instructors git repo for this lesson and created a new firebase firestore app for his clone. And YES I am changing out my own API information!

Also possibly the most peculiar part about this, is that the Users collection (using firebase for authentication) is updating when a user logs in! But the other one is not appearing.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey: ...
  authDomain: ...
  projectId: ...
  storageBucket: ...
  messagingSenderId: ...
  appId: ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);

  const snapShot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapShot.exists) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error creating user', error.message);
    }
  }

  return userRef;
};

export const addCollectionAndDocuments = async (
  collectionKey,
  objectsToAdd
) => {
  const collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionKey);

  const batch = firestore.batch();
  objectsToAdd.forEach(obj => {
    const newDocRef = collectionRef.doc();
    batch.set(newDocRef, obj);
  });

  return await batch.commit();
};

export const convertCollectionsSnapshotToMap = collections => {
  const transformedCollection = collections.docs.map(doc => {
    const { title, items } = doc.data();

    return {
      routeName: encodeURI(title.toLowerCase()),
      id: doc.id,
      title,
      items
    };
  });

  return transformedCollection.reduce((accumulator, collection) => {
    accumulator[collection.title.toLowerCase()] = collection;
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
};

export const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      unsubscribe();
      resolve(userAuth);
    }, reject);
  });
};

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);

export default firebase;
```

Comment: What are your firestore rules? Any error message?

Comment: Have you verified that your .set code is definitely running ?

Comment: My rules are simply 

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 11, 29);
    }
  }
}

Comment: I'm new to firebase and react for that matter. How do I check if .set code is running?

Comment: I did have console.log(newDocRef) in there to see if I am logging the 5 document reference objects I trying to store. But I failed to find where that is located in dev tools.

Comment: @windowsill Any other advice you can offer?

Comment: I assume it is the `userRef.set` code that you are expecting to write into the users collection. Are you sure it's running? Because it's in an if block...

Comment: Actually I figured out what was going on....I was trying to add data from shop.data.js, my goal was to add in the data so I didnt have to manually add it into the firestore db. Well, I accidentally deleted that file before it could get added the first time. I was supposed to delete that file after it runs the batch the first time....whoops! Rookie mistake.